# Liquid Script based on Conditional JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, liquid

Let's suppose we have a dropdown toggle:

```
<label for="num-of-records">Rows per Page: </label>
<select name="num-of-records" id="num-of-records">
  <option value="" selected>default</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

And we also have a `liquid` code:

```
{% include 'page' key: 'table' %}
```

For `key`, I have provide some options `table`,`table25`, and `table50` for each dropdown options value.

I am new to `liquid`, but I want to create a `jquery` which select the `key` value based on the dropdown.

```
<script>
$(this).append("{% include 'page' key: 'table"+ $.("#num-of-records").val()+"' %}"
</script>
```

So let's say I choose option `25`, so it will (maybe reopen the page) append `liquid` script of:

```
{% include 'page' key: 'table25' %}
```

Comment: I don't think `$.(this)` is valid jQuery. You probably mean `$(this)`. You also can't use jQuery inside of a liquid expression.

Comment: Since Liquid is rendered on the server and jQuery is executed on the client you can not just combine them like that. It would help to know the exact use case here to help you find a solid solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liquid is a server side rendered language. jQuery is rendered after Liquid so you cannot proceed this way.

An approach that could work (not a light one however) could be to render all your Liquid cases, hide them, then show the one you want by using jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The approach you propose are quite helpful. This may be the best idea.